# Is there any way to specify a parametrized test id inside the param set itself instead of as a separate array?

Tags: python, pytest

We can use `ids=[]` to name the param sets:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    'a, b',
    [
        (1, {'Two Scoops of Django': '1.8'}),
        (True, 'Into the Brambles'),
        ('Jason likes cookies', [1, 2, 3]),
        (PYTEST_PLUGIN, 'plugin_template'),
    ], ids=[
        'int and dict',
        'bool and str',
        'str and list',
        'CookiecutterTemplate and str',
    ]
)
def test_foobar(a, b):
    assert True
```

But I really hate how it's a separate list like this because I have to count to figure out which param set matches up with the test id name.

For heavily parametrized() tests I've taken to this which is unpleasant as well:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    'a, b',
    [
        # int and dict
        (1, {'Two Scoops of Django': '1.8'}),
        # bool and str
        (True, 'Into the Brambles'),
        # str and list
        ('Jason likes cookies', [1, 2, 3]),
        # CookiecutterTemplate and str
        (PYTEST_PLUGIN, 'plugin_template'),
    ], ids=[
        'int and dict',
        'bool and str',
        'str and list',
        'CookiecutterTemplate and str',
    ]
)
def test_foobar(a, b):
    assert True
```

Is there support for specifying the id name inside the param set instead? If possible something like this:

```
[
    id="int and dict", (1, {'Two Scoops of Django': '1.8'}),
    id="bool and str", (True, 'Into the Brambles'),
    etc
```

Comment: You can see the options in [the docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/parametrize.html#paramexamples). If none fit your needs/preferences why not write your own decorator that turns the dicts (assuming that's what you want; currently it's invalid syntax) into the lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`pytest.param`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html?highlight=param#pytest.param):

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    'a, b',
    [
        # int and dict
        pytest.param(1, {'Two Scoops of Django': '1.8'}, id='int and dict'),
        # bool and str
        pytest.param(True, 'Into the Brambles', id='bool and str'),
        # str and list
        pytest.param('Jason likes cookies', [1, 2, 3], id='str and list'),
        # CookiecutterTemplate and str
        pytest.param(PYTEST_PLUGIN, 'plugin_template', id='CookiecutterTemplate and str'),
    ]
)
def test_foobar(a, b):
    assert True
```